# Django: filtering model from related field

Tags: python, django

In Django I have the following models: *Person*, *Device*, *Consumption*

> A *Person* can have zero to many *Devices* 
> A *Device* can have
>   zero to many *Consumptions*

How can I filter Persons on a value in Consumption?

I can filter on fields from Devices:

```
Person.objects.filter(device__is_active=True)
```

But how can I filter on Consumption fields?

Answer (score 2):

To get a `Consumption` object (in this case by its ID) you would do the following:

```
Person.objects.filter(device__consumptions__id=consumption_id)
```

Comment: device__consumption... (no *s*)

Comment: `A Device can have zero to many Consumptions` so in this case the query is on the device's consumption set (which may be called `consumption_set`by default).